# Regex: How to identify column attributes from create table statement

Tags: sql, .net, regex, oracle

I want to translate some table create statements from Oracle into SQL Server. The approach I am taking is to pick out the important keywords using a regex match. I seem to be able to identify the part of the statement that concerns the column definitions, but I can't quite get a regex pattern to cater for all the possible values of a column specification. The attributes I am interested in are

- Column Name
- Column Type
- Type Parameters (if any)
- Default Value (if any)
- Not Null (if set)

Here is a sample set of column definitions in Oracle:

```
a1" NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT "ca1" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "a2" NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT "ca2" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "a3" NUMBER(14,0) DEFAULT 0 CONSTRAINT "ca3" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "a4" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR), 
    "a5" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "a6" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 0 CONSTRAINT "ca6" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "a7" NUMBER(5,0) DEFAULT 0 CONSTRAINT "ca7" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "a8" NUMBER(5,0) DEFAULT 0 CONSTRAINT "ca8" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "abc" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "def" CHAR(3 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ghi" CHAR(3 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "XML" CLOB NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "jkl" CHAR(6 CHAR), 
    "mno" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "pqr" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
```

And here is the regex pattern I have so far

```
(?i)("?)(?<colname>\w+)("?)(\s+)(?<type>\w+)((?<typepars>\((\w|\s|\,)+\))?)(\s+default\s+(?<defaultval>(null|\w|\'\s\')+?))?(\s+constraint\s+\"?\w+\"?\s+(?<nullable>not\snull)\senable)?(,?)(\s*)(?-i)
```

I am using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to build the pattern and my target environment is .Net.

I am using named groups for all the attributes I am interested in. Any help would be appreciated. Also, there are a lot of tables and columns I need this for so I can't guarantee that the above sample is fully representative. I will only know once I try to run it for everything.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/JmQ6bH/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal recommendation would be to query the [Postgres Catalog Tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalogs.html) instead, as they already have the relevant information in a convenient way.

The following regex matches (and somewhat structures) the SQL fragments you have:

```
  (?i)^\s*("?)(?>(?<colname>\w+))\1
   \s+
   (?:(?<type>\b\w+\b)\s*(?:\((?<typepars>(?:\w|\s|\,|\*)+)\))?)
   \s*
   (\bdefault\s+(?<defaultval>(\(?)(null|\w+|\'\s\')+?\)?))?
   \s*
   (?:(?:\bconstraint\s+(")(?<constraint_name>\w+)\9\s+)?(?<nullable>not\s+null\b)\s+enable)?
   (,?)(\s*)(?-i)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/GHOIcS/2